# Disable PIN requirement for Kid's Corner?

Tags: kids-corner

I have enabled Kid's Corner like many other parents so my child is restricted to a bunch of games and apps I have pre-selected, so he obviously doesn't move/delete my tiles around or use any apps he shouldn't.

However I am finding that whenever he swipes up to enter his Kid's Corner, it's prompting him for my PIN? This seems like a seriously wacky design flaw, and just causes annoyance as I have to keep entering the PIN for him.

Is it possible to allow him to access his corner without a PIN, but obviously prompt for PIN on mine? I don't know if this was intentional or on purpose by MS, it seems like a very strange design choice.

Answer (score 2):

By design the kids corner have no PIN.
Your PIN should only be asked for when you try to log in on the non kids corner side.

The problem however is that if you have your phone connected to a domain that domain might have a group policy forcing your phone into always asking for the PIN. This will also make the phone ask for PIN inside the kids corner.

I think they've made this choice because even though you choose what to put in kids corner, the apps put there might include sensitive information. Because of that the Kids corner is also under the rules of group policy. Unfortunatly :/

Comment: the strange thing is that Microsoft's own Exchange servers have that policy, so if you connect an @microsoft.com email address to the phone, you must have a PIN. If Exchange is somehow making Kids Corner less useful, you would think Microsoft employees would notice...

Comment: My phone isn't connected to a domain, I just have a regular link up in accounts via windows live and google accounts. Can somebody confirm if they receive a PIN prompt when PIN is turned on for regular use?

Comment: I do, thats a pet issue with me as well @GONeale

Comment: So frustrating, let's hope it changes in Windows Phone Blue. I might submit a bug report.

Comment: It works for me, I have a PIN on my normal home screen and no pin on kids corner.